# Combinatorics w/ binary string

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, bit-strings

How many string of 16 bit can we build having the following constraints:

1. There must be **exactly** 5 one
2. Between two 1 there must be **at least** two 0.

Example of valid string:

(1) 1 00 1 00 1 00 1 00 1 000

(3) 0 1 00 1 00 1 00 1 00 1 00

(3) 1 0000 1 00 1 00 1 000 1

I have no clue how to approach problems like these. I know the answer (which is 56) but I do not know the logic behind that.

Comment: Arrange the five $1's$ with gaps as in $\_1\_1\_1\_1\_1\_$.  Let $g_i$ be the number of $0's$ in each gap. We know that $g_2,\cdots, g_5$ must be at least $2$.  So let $G_i=g_i-2$ for $i\in \{2,3,4,5\}$.  Then just use [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) on $g_1, G_2, G_3, G_4, G_5, g_6$.

Comment: are you familiar with stars and bars?

Comment: @Phicar no can you explain how to use it here?

Comment: @Jonathan Just follow lulu's explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the length of the string is 16 and there are $5$ ones, there must be $11$ zeros.

Now, place the ones on the line, as _ $1$ _ $1$ _ $1$ _ $1$ _ $1$ _, we have 2 gaps at each end, and 4 gaps in the middle of the ones, for a total of 6 gaps. Now denote the number of zeros in each gap $g_i$, with $ i \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$, then from the given conditions, $g_2,g_3,g_4,g_5$ must be larger than or equal to $2$, and thus $G_i=g_i -2 \ge 0$ for all $i \in \{ 2,3,4,5 \}$

So we have the sum $ g_1 +G_2 +G_3+G_4+G_5 +g_6 = 3$, which means divide $3$ balls in to $6$ groups, each group might have a non-negative number of balls. The formula for this division is $ \binom {8}{3}$, which you may see the explanation in the **Star and Bar** link mentioned above

Comment: I tried and work!!! Also this video help a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMm6mR7AznY&t=244s

Comment: Great job, congrats